# How to manually add Compiled Knockout Template in DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, jquery-masonry

I am using [Salvattore jQuery Masonry](http://salvattore.com/) to display items in grid. The items are rendered using Knockout Template before Salvattore is initialized.

For example:

```
<div id="grid">
    <!-- ko foreach: aItems -->
    <div>
       <div data-bind="template: { name: 'xyz-template', data: $data }">
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>

<script>
    salvattore.registerGrid(document.getElementById("grid"));
</script>
```

but whenever item changes i have to manually add item using following script

```
<script>
    var grid = document.querySelector('#grid');
    var item = document.createElement('article');

    // Note in my case item is going to be my complied knockout template
    salvattore.appendElements(grid, [item]);
</script>
```

but to do so i need to have Complied Knockout template. How can i compile my Knockout Template manually so i can add it using salvattore.appendElements method? Or is there any workaround which i can use?

Note: Salvattore jQuery Masonry itself handle rendering DOM in grid so knockout wont have any effect once plugin is initialized.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the renderTemplate knockout function to programmatically render the template within a given DOM element:

```
ko.renderTemplate("xyz-template",itemData,{},item,"replaceChildren");
```